# Can a pointer inside a class point to this?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm implementing a min heap with an extra property of saving the max key between the children.
I have a Node class, and in case the Node is a leaf I want it to point back to itself.
Something like:

```
class Node
{
    public:
    void update max()
    {
      if ((left==NULL)&&(right==NULL))
           max=this;
    }


    private:
    Key* key;
    Value* val;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* max;
}
```

The reason is that right now it points to NULL and it makes me check too many times if max is NULL before comparing the Keys.
I should also mention that I'm using all these pointers since Key and Value are pure virtual, and Node has a derived class which I'll be using.
Anyway.. Is it possible to have a member variable pointing to this?

Comment: _"Is it possible to have a member variable pointing to this?"_ Why do you think it couldn't be possible? Sounds like you're asking about XY-problem. Clarify what's your actual problem please.

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running it?

Comment: `max` is a pointer. `this` is a pointer. Don't you wanna be a pointer too?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I have too many memory leak so it doesn't run.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm trying to understand if it's legal for a variable inside a class to point to the class itself. If I make an instance A of Node, is it possible for the member "max" of the instance A to point to this?

Comment: @user4581301 No thanks, I don't wanna be leaking :)

Comment: @L.S Again: What makes you think that it should be _illegal_?

Comment: This is an X-Y question and requires a good discussion on Resource Ownership. I'm unable to find a good SO link that is up to date and doesn't spend all of its time on smart pointers (a good solution, but doesn't explain the concept) so you may have to go diving into textbooks and papers. Here's one by three folk generally respected for knowing their stuff: http://www.stroustrup.com/resource-model.pdf

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

`This` is by definition the reference/pointer to the object that the object holds itself. 
Nothing forbids you to save that reference value into something else